# How to split a csv file into tab separated according a specific column using bash

Tags: bash

I have a CSV file with almost 190 column exported from SQL data. Now I would like to split the single CSV\XLS whichever support into multiple sheets based on specific column say,

```
   Sample.csv
   id  name  technology  User  Countries   Support_Place Support_Contacts
   1   aaa     SQL       user1   US          US1           6766678
   2   bbb    Linux      user2   Japan       Japan2        9878678
   3   ccc     Java      user3    India      India3        6545654

  Expecting,

   Sample.csv
   sheet1
   ====
   id  name  technology  
   1   aaa     SQL       
   2   bbb    Linux     
   3   ccc     Java      

   User Sheet2
   ==============
     User  Countries  
     user1   US    
     user2   Japan 
     user3    India

  Support_Place Sheet3
 =====================
     Support_Place Support_Contacts
       US1           6766678
      Japan2        9878678
      India3        6545654
```

Based on specific column I would like to split the data say from Users column to Countries column in Sheet2 and from Support_Place column to Support Contacts in sheet3,etc.

Note: The column headers are fixed.

Please let me know how this can be achieved using bash script. Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: There is a WIDE gulf between "CSV" and "Excel". You can pretty easily split this thing into multiple CSV files using tools like `awk` on the command line, but creating an actual xlsx file and creating multiple sheets is going to take something more powerful python with a module that can deal with excel.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting this out to multiple csv files using awk would look like:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{print $1,$2,$3 > "split1.csv"; print $4,$5 > "split2.csv"; print $6, $7 > "split3.csv"}' yourfile.csv
```

As I mentioned, getting this out to a multi-tab excel file is going to be more in the realm of python or similar language that can handle such a job.

Comment: :Great! Thanks!This command splits the CSV but adds my last column value in split1.csv along.